# Doctrine update error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I get this error:

> Error: Method Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison::__toString() must not throw an exception
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException

When this code gets run:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->update('Model:Defect', 'd')
        ->set('d.task', $task)
        ->where('d.defectId IN :defectIds')
        ->setParameter('defectIds', $defectIds)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

What is wrong with that?

Thank you

Comment: add your entity to question. btw, see also [this](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/551), [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/P6gp3msDWqE) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864051/in-method-typo3-queryinterface)

Comment: can you add what do you have in $task and $defectIds variables?